# Can't access web service methods, but can access the MethodNameCompletedEventArgs and MethodNameCompletedEventHandler

Tags: c#, web-services

This is my first time dealing with making my own web service, and I made a basic one, which I am currently only needing to access locally:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
namespace WebService1
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        #region Temp Conversion
        [WebMethod]
        public string F2C(int f)
        {
            double c = 5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32);
            return c.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This works when I run this and run the method through the browser. However I've added it to another project, a windows form application, via "Add Service Reference" < Advanced

But now within the project when I try to access the methods they don't show. 
I do:

```
MyWebService.
```

I named the referenced service "MyWebService", and all thats available is:

```
F2CCompletedEventHandler
F2CCompletedEventArgs
Service1
```

as opposed to

```
MyWebService.F2C
```

On its own being available right away.

Comment: you need to create an Instance of the myWebService object can you show the code where you are consuming / creating the proxy and or instance..? sounds like you need to use fully qualified name in regards to the namespace + the class name

Comment: @MethodMan Oh I completely forgot to do that, added "MyWebService.Service1 myService = new MyWebService.Service1();" to the start, now its fine xD thanks.

Comment: I entered it as an answer.. that's something I noticed right away.. it's a simple oversight that most of us do.. I am glad that I was able to quickly answer your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an Instance of the myWebService object can you show the code where you are consuming / creating the proxy and or instance..? sounds like you need to use fully qualified name in regards to the namespace + the class name

Example:

```
MyWebService.Service1 myService = new MyWebService.Service1();
```

to call the method do the following

```
myService.F2C(15); // for example
```